# Does a Borel transform uniquely determine a Borel measure?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, measure-theory

It is a known fact that Borel measures are uniquely determined by their Fourier transforms. This is the motivation for the following question.

I came across the concept of a Borel transform of a Borel measure. Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and let $\mu$ be a Borel measure. Letting:
$$\mathbb{C}_{+} := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im}z > 0\},$$
the Borel transform of $\mu$ is defined as the function $F: \mathbb{C}_{+} \to \mathbb{C}_{+}$ given by:
$$F(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{x-z}d\mu(x) $$

So, my question is: do Borel transforms uniquely determine a Borel measure? In other words, if:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{x-z}d\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{x-z}d\nu(x)$$
holds for every $z \in \mathbb{C}_{+}$ for some other Borel measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, does it follow that $\mu = \nu$?

This is a new concept for me, so that this might be a standard result. However, I have looked for this result on the internet, and found nothing about it.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a standard result. The measure is determined by $F$ and in fact it can be recovered as $d\mu(x) = \lim_{y\to 0+}(1/\pi)\textrm{Im }F(x+iy)\, dx$ (in weak $*$ sense).

Comment: This is discussed in many spectral theory books, for example Section 3.4 here: https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/index.html

Comment: You need to impose a growth condition at infty on your measure to ensure that "Borel transform" exists. (A more common name for this is Cauchy transform, btw).